# Browser compatibility issue for tabs experience in MS Teams Client

Tags: tabs, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

We have tabs experience in our Teams app using [Oauth SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad?tabs=teamsjs-v2) (authentication.authenticate() method of the TeamsJS SDK).
We have several customers using Azure AD as the OAuth IdP who are getting the following error after authentication with Teams desktop (screenshot below)

> #### You can’t get there from here
>
> This application contains sensitive information and can only be accessed from:
>
> - Devices or client applications that meet [customer name] management compliance policy
>
> The current browser is not supported, please use Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, Chrome or Firefox 91+ to access this application.

[image: Browser compatibility issue]

Our customers were able to access this tab until recently.

There was no update in our code recently and as far as we know, no change from our customers regarding their Azure AD Conditional Access policies.
Note that for one of our customers

- The Apps condition is [not configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g5XN.png) in the Azure AD Conditional Access.
- They say on their side they can access other applications with the Conditional Access, and only our app seems blocked this way.

Have there been recent changes related to the Conditional Access that could explain this behavior? Or is there a known fix/workaround we should try here to solve our customers' issue?

Comment: Please have look into this document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/troubleshoot-conditional-access#conditional-access-sign-in-interrupt

Meanwhile we are checking it from our side as well and get back to you.

Comment: Hello Sayali. Error is occurring with Teams Desktop.

Comment: If you are the only one experiencing this issue, you may log into the same URL with your account through one of your colleague's computers if it's convenient, this can identify whether this issue is related to the local environment.

Comment: We are able to repro that issue, we have raised bug for the same, we will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: This issue has been fixed since July 2023. Please do verify.